# MongoDB return subTotal and total in a single query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this data in a collection:

```
{id:1, types:{'A':4, 'B': 3, 'C':12}}
{id:1, types:{'A':8, 'B': 2, 'C':11}}
{id:2, types:{'A':7, 'B': 6, 'C':14}}
{id:3, types:{'A':1, 'B': 9, 'C':15}}
```

I want to query for the total of each **type** for **id:1** but I also want to know the totals for each **type** for all **id**s in a single query. I would like the output to look something like this:

```
{id:1, types:{'A':12, 'B':5, 'C':12, 'sumA':20,'sumB':20,'sumC':52}}
```

I can do this by calling 2 separate queries. One query containing

```
 {$match: {id:1}}
```

And one that does not have a $match option. But I would like to know if it can be done in a single query.

Edit: types A,B and C are dynamic so I won't know the values beforehand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query.

`$group` aggregation with `$sum` to calculate total count and `$cond` to limit the count for specific id.

```
db.col.aggregate([
 {"$group":{
   "_id":null,
   "sumA":{"$sum":"$types.A"},
   "sumB":{"$sum":"$types.B"},
   "sumC":{"$sum":"$types.C"},
   "A":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$id",1]},"$types.A",0]}},
   "B":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$id",1]},"$types.B",0]}},
   "C":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$id",1]},"$types.C",0]}},
  }}
])
```

Update to below structure

```
{id:1, types:[{"k":'A', v:4}, { "k":'B', "v": 3}, { "k":'C', "v": 12}]}
{id:1, types:[{"k":'A', v:8}, { "k":'B', "v": 2}, { "k":'C', "v": 11}]}
{id:2, types:[{"k":'A', v:7}, { "k":'B', "v": 6}, { "k":'C', "v": 14}]}
{id:3, types:[{"k":'A', v:1}, { "k":'B', "v": 9}, { "k":'C', "v": 15}]}
```

Aggregation query:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$types"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$types.k",
    "sum":{"$sum":"$types.v"},
    "type":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$id",1]},"$types.v",0]}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if the types (A,B and C) are dynamic? I forgot to include that in my question.

Comment: Np. There may be a may in 3.4 using `objectToArray` and `arrayToObject` but are not performant solutions. You will be better off updating structure to `{id:1, types:[{"k":'A', v:4}, { "k":'B', "v": 3}....]}` and I can update the aggregation to query from new structure. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes I can update my data structure to look like what you have suggested. I will also look into the objectToArray and arrayToObject methods. Thank you!